# JProfiler asking for IntelliJ Configuration Director (.IntelliJ...)

Tags: intellij-idea, jprofiler

I tried to install JProfiler integrated with IntelliJ 10 on MacOS. The installer tries to locate a 'IntelliJ configuration folder' which I dont have and I dont know how to create.

Any assistance or hints would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the corresponding [IntelliJ IDEA FAQ article](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

> ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea10

**Windows:**

> C:\Users\user.IntelliJIdea2017.2